# Why is the canvas not drawing a line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is my first time using a canvas and was trying to test it by drawing a line through the specified coordinates. Can someone explain why it is not working?

```
const c = document.getElementById("chessBoard");
const canvas = c.getContext("2d");

canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(75, 0);
canvas.lineTo(75, 600);
canvas.stroke();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Chess Project</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="board.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <header id="header">
                Chess Project
            </header>
        </section>
        <section>
            <canvas id="chessBoard"></canvas>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#chessBoard {
    position: absolute;
    left: 550px;
    top: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

If someone could please take a look at the code and give me any advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your code is in `board.js` then it's because your script is running too soon - before the element exists.  Move `<script src=board.js></script>` to the end of the html or wrap in some form of DOM ready event.

Comment: When doing browser-based development, it's really useful to have the console open. In this case, you'd have seen an error trying to call `getContext` on `null`, because your code is running before the canvas element exists. See [the linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) for details.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `canvas.closePath()` after `canvas.stroke()` to draw the line.

Comment: The OP doesn't need `closePath`, `lineTo`+`stroke` draws the line. See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath Their code works just fine if they run it *after* the `canvas` element has been put in the DOM. (`closePath` is useful for closing polygons, but that's not what their doing.)